# React full stack project Login Form

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt

I am making a full-stack website using react and Microsoft SQL Server, however, I am stuck with the functionality of the login page.

What are the best practices for this to be done?

So far I have a simple login form and a table in the DB for users. What I was thinking (for the first iteration of this development) is to do a simple query to the users table to see if the email and password exists.

Can I restrict react-router-dom from opening a page depending on if the user exists within a table? I understand that JWT authentication will be needed?

I am simply looking for pointers for how a login form such as this should work.

Comment: You can create an HOC component that checks if the user is authenticated against the state before rendering the route. you login reducer should update the state with data that will help you to determine if the user is authenticated or not (Can be simple boolean, or can store the role and permissions).
Make sure that you DO NOT store plain text passwords in you SQL, store and compare only hashes of the passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most login functionalities will have a login form asking for email and password. You can follow the below steps,

1.) In the backend, you need to check whether the user-password combination exists.

2.) If it exists then generate a JSON web token with the userId and send that to the frontend. Store the jwt in localStorage/sessionStorage/cookies.

3.) For each and every HTTP request the jwt will be sent to the backend in request headers.

4.) You can extract the userId from the jwt. You should then check whether the user has permission to do a particular operation in the backend. You can also restrict the user from viewing certain pages using the userId.

5.) Pages like login/register need not be displayed in frontend after a successful sign-in. You can implement the logic in react based on the local storage of jwt.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I will follow these instructions and see where it leads me :)